# Rails: rendering collections as tr with a table around it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, collections, partial-views

I typically have the following partials per resource, e.g. for `user`:

- `_users` which holds the `table` definition with `thead` and `tbody`
- `_user` which holds one `tr`

It would be nice to render everything with a shortcut like this:

```
= render @users
```

But this sadly doesn't take the `_users` container into account, so I always have to do this:

```
= render 'users', users: @users
```

And then within `_users` partial I can do:

```
= render users
```

Isn't there a shortcut for this? Maybe something like this:

```
= render @users, wrapper: true
= render @users, wrapper: 'users'
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I got it right, but I'll try to take a guess. The way I understood your problem I would solve it like this:

**_users.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render @users %> # this will render   _user.html.erb
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**_user.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <td><%= user.name %></td>
</tr>
```

That should work, at least it does for me. Let me know if I didn't understood correctly your question.

Comment: That's exactly the way I'm doing it now. I only don't understand why one can do `render @users` where the user partial is a `tr` which always needs a table context surrounding it.

Comment: Well, consider the table that surrounds it to be like a layout for your data, and when you do `render @users` it's like you'll do `users.each do |user|  render partial: 'user', user: user end` that means looping through each `user` in `users` collection. 5 users you'll have in db, 5 times this partial will be rendered creating the `tr`(table row) for each record. `render @users` is just a shortcut to `@users.each do |user|`

Comment: I completely understand the logic behind `render @users`, but why is there a `:spacer` option for placing a layout element between each rendered partial, but no `:layout` option for one partial surrounding the whole thing.